# Hello, world and android emulator not starting all the way up!

Tags: android, android-emulator

I followed the tutorial to the letter. I select run then the emulator starts up. Problem is that I never get to a home screen, nor does the text hello world display.

Is there a way to test my installation of the emulator?

Comment: If you're still not seeing what you want, just paste your Console text from Exclipse onto here.

Answer (score 3):

Take into account that the android emulator takes some time to load.

Wait for a few minutes and check logs on the `DDMS` to see if everything is loading correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It does take a while to start up. But remember that you don't need to close and run the emulator every time you want to test your project. Just leave it open and it'll just launch your application when you want to run it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and discovered (by clicking all the buttons in the emulator) that if you press the home button (little house) then the launcher icon (grid of squares) that the app I was launching had been successfully installed and I could run it by clicking on it.  I still don't know why running it from Eclipse wasn't getting all the way into the app,  but at least it was installed and I could run it from the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold the power button in the emulator.

Comment: Nothing seems to work. I guess I need to look at the logCat and start troubleshooting.

Comment: The power button is the only one that "works"... how long should I hold it for?  Tried for 10 seconds, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the time and patience, check out this site:

http://bid.berkeley.edu/cs160-fall10/index.php/Tips_and_Tricks

It provides a great walkthrough on installation and setting up Android development. See if you miss any steps?